# How to alter a PNG icon in Qt

Tags: qt

The effect I wanted to achieve is something like the Mail icon in iPhone. There is a rounded rectangle on the topright corner of the Mail icon. The number inside the rectangle shows the current number of unread emails and can be dynamically changed when new emails come in. I am wondering if it is possible to do this using Qt 4.6 for a desktop application interface. If it is possible, what classes should I start to learn? (I guess Qt should have some bitmap manipulation class.) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw into a [QImage](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimage.html) or QPixmap using [QPianter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpainter.html), then save the icon to a png file - or since you are using it in your app, just change the internal icon directly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [QImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qimage.html) and [QPainter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qpainter.html).